# Inconsistent behaviour with Null Type in Scala

Tags: scala, null

According to the [scala docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Null):

> Null is a subtype of all reference types;

So in theory, in this example we can assume `Null` is a subtype of `Foo` (a reference type) and that we should be able to attempt to call the `bar` method on an instance of type `Null`. In practice we can't and the code snippet fails at compile time with the error `value bar is not a member of Null`.

---

```
case class Foo(bar: String)

val n: Null = null
n.bar
```

[Try it](http://www.scalakata.com/524e82fbe4b0b1a1c4da95e3)

---

I think it makes sense that we catch this at compile time because as the scala docs also [say](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Null) `[Null's] only instance is the null reference`, however I think a better error message would be `Calling bar on type Null can only result in a NullPointerException`.

My question is regarding the following code snippet, which doesn't fail at compile time and instead fails at runtime with a `NullPointerException`

---

```
val n: Null = null
n.toString
```

[Try it](http://www.scalakata.com/524e8c46e4b0b1a1c4da95e5)

---

I am assuming this is because the Null type doesn't truly subclass every other reference type and only subclasses `AnyRef`, but is there any reason why this shouldn't throw a compile time error (or at least warning) that this code can only result in a `NullPointerException`? Is it deliberate that calling `null.bar` and `null.toString` behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

`Null is a subtype of all reference types;` - this means something like that:

```
val n: Foo = null
n.bar //throws NPE

val a: String = null
a.charAt(0) //NPE again
```

So you can say `Null` is a subtype of all reference types.

**edit:** The

```
val n: Null = null 
n.bar
```

part is incorrect. According to Scala docs:

```
abstract final class Null extends AnyRef
```

`AnyRef` doesnt' have a `bar`. You cannot say like this, right?

```
val n: AnyRef = ""
n.charAt(0) //won't compile
```

Comment: But surely those two statements conflict? In [this](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/pl2009/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node28.html) definition of subtyping `Type B is a subtype of A if every function that can be invoked on an object of type A can also be invoked on an object of type B.` If my example if you cannot call `.bar` on type `Null` then type `Null` is not a subtype `Bar`.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but it seems like this expression (`val n: Foo = null`) translates to something like "Let the `Null` be a subtype of `Foo`" and so the `val n: Null = null` translates to a simple `Null`. Consider two classes - `Foo(bar: String)` and `Bar(foo: String)`. In this case if you write `val n: Null = null` which subtype should it be?

Comment: It should be a subtype of both `Foo` and `Bar`, but that is a good point; multiple class inheritance is not possible in scala, so it can't be. I've been viewing subtyping and inheritance as the same thing, but maybe they need to be considered as different things in Scala.